# SOQL select columns with names that contain specific word

Tags: apex, soql

Right now I have a lots of field that that with the word "location"
Is there an SOQL command that could help me to select all the fields in a specific object that contains the word Location

Something like
Select id, fields("location") from case

thx you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an SOQL command that could help me to select all the fields in a specific object that contains the word Location

No.

However, you can build a dynamic SOQL statement:

```
String[] fields = new String[0];
for(String fieldName: sObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().keySet()) {
  if(fieldName.containsIgnoreCase('location')) {
    fields.add(fieldName);
  }
}
sObject[] results = Database.query(
  'SELECT '+String.join(fields,',')+' FROM Account'
);
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not.

SOQL and SOSL generally demand that you explicitly list out all of the fields that you wish to query. `FIELDS([ALL|CUSTOM|STANDARD])`, and the automatic inclusion of the Id field (and RecordTypeId if the SObject has at least one custom record type defined for it) are the only exceptions to that at this time. In Apex, we can only use `FIELDS(STANDARD)`.

If you only want to query a few (say, less than 15) fields, and *only those fields*, your best option is probably just to type them all out manually. Beyond that, you could use the information from SObject's Describe to get *all* of the fields on a given object (e.g. `Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().keySet()`), and then iterate over them to filter out the ones that don't start with 'location' (`startsWith()` is a String method). You'd need to build a dynamic query to use that approach though.

As a final note, if you truly do have that many "location*" fields, that's likely a sign of poor design. It sounds to me like you should consider creating a new SObject to hold multiple pieces of location data (rather than having X number of fields on your current object).

Comment: Does having a lot of fields on an object impact performance or anything else ? We are in fact recording checkbox tags on the case object

Comment: @Ben2pop The performance impact is likely to be minimal. At worst, I think it'd slightly increase the heap space that your code uses. The more pressing issue, I think, is that it's a waste of effort. If you use an object to represent this data, you just need to insert another record. If you track it in fields, then every modification means you need to add a new field (and worry about FLS when deploying) in addition to modifying code. In the end, I think that making an additional object is going to be less work than adding additional fields (and this type of "laziness" is generally good).

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't one. You can only use FIELDS(ALL), FIELDS(CUSTOM) or FIELD(STANDARD) to fetch all fields or custom fields or standard fields respectively.

However, you can query `FieldDefinition` object (available as a part of [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm)) and use the result to easily get all the field name containing the word 'location' in it. Sample query given below:

```
select id, DataType, DeveloperName from FieldDefinition where EntityDefinition.DeveloperName = '<SObjectName>'
```